# How to Make CSS Property Apply to Everything Within Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, parent-child

I have a Navbar in Bootstrap 3, and want the background of the dropdowns on it to be the same color as the navbar. I do not expressly set any colors now, other than that of .navbar. How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.navbar{
  background-color:pink;
  background-image:none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu{
  background-color:pink;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  line-height:30px;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Here's a working [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ypgaop).

Comment: This doesn't work when the dropdown elements are moused over. That's why I was trying to see if there was a way to override the property on all children. If that isn't possible, what is the specific element needed to be edited to resolve this?

Comment: does it fit your requirement? sorry for bad colors.